# MySQL 8.0.20 Bug? Resulting groups duplicated when using GROUP BY and COUNT(DISTINCT )

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

UPDATE: filed a bug with MySQL: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=100107

The same code consistently produces the expected result when run using MySQL 8.0.16, but consistently produces the confusing result when run in MySQL 8.0.20. Multiple students have confirmed the same bug presenting when run on 8.0.20 on their machines, all running MySQL Community Server locally, using MySQL Workbench.

The code which produces the duplicated rows is immediately below. Pretty simple query to create a monthly trend of a count of website sessions for a given time period:

```
 SELECT 
    YEAR(website_sessions.created_at) AS yr, 
    MONTH(website_sessions.created_at) AS mon,
    COUNT(DISTINCT website_session_id) AS session_volume 
FROM website_sessions
WHERE website_sessions.created_at BETWEEN '2012-04-01' AND '2013-04-05' 
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

The query shown immediately above consistently produces 2 groups for 2012-11, 3 groups for 2012-12, 3 groups for 2013-1, and 2 groups for 2013-2.

```
yr, mon, session_volume
2012, 4, 3734
2012, 5, 3736
2012, 6, 3963
2012, 7, 4249
2012, 8, 6097
2012, 9, 6546
2012, 10, 8183
2012, 11, 13979
2012, 12, 9827
2012, 11, 32
2012, 12, 208
2013, 1, 3545
2012, 12, 37
2013, 1, 2820
2013, 2, 4350
2013, 1, 36
2013, 2, 2818
2013, 3, 6264
2013, 4, 1209
```

If we remove DISTINCT from inside the COUNT( ) function, the duplication does not present itself. The code immediately below runs fine, without dupes:

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(website_sessions.created_at) AS yr, 
    MONTH(website_sessions.created_at) AS mon,
    COUNT(website_session_id) AS session_volume 
FROM website_sessions
WHERE website_sessions.created_at BETWEEN '2012-04-01' AND '2013-04-05' 
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Alternatively, if we use DATE_FORMAT( ) instead of the YEAR() and MONTH( ) functions to create our trend groups, we can still use DISTINCT with no duplication. See query immediately below:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(website_sessions.created_at,'%Y') AS yr, 
    DATE_FORMAT(website_sessions.created_at,'%M') AS mon,
    COUNT(DISTINCT website_session_id) AS session_volume
FROM website_sessions
WHERE website_sessions.created_at BETWEEN '2012-04-01' AND '2013-04-05' 
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

The first of the 3 queries is the only one that produces duplicate groups. The second and third query never produces duplicates.

We have used the same COUNT(DISTINCT ) methodology for years, without seeing this duplication issue that has only occurred in version 8.0.20 to my knowledge.

The queries and their outputs are shown below as a side-by-side comparison in the attached image.

Anyone have any ideas how we can be seeing the same values in our GROUP columns when using GROUP BY here? Or any ideas as to why eliminating DISTINCT or using DATE_FORMAT( ) does not produce the same problem?

[3 queries - 1 dupe, 2 no dupe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vx7Zs.jpg)

Comment: As you describe this, it certainly sounds like a bug.

Comment: sounds like you should report this as a bug to [the relevant place](https://bugs.mysql.com/how-to-report.php)

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly. Filed a bug per your direction. Appreciate it. 

Linked to bug at top of ticket for anyone else finding this and needed help.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0